# Analog synthesizer- Add second VCO

Tags: analog, oscillator, synthesizer

I am working on reviving an old synth design (Transcendent 2000), but I would like to add a second oscillator. I was thinking of doubling the circuit highlighted below, and sharing the pitch control (non-highlighted sections) between the two oscillators. I was planning on using a second tuning circuit (circled section) to detune the second oscillator. I would also like to add hard sync between both oscillators. Would this idea work, and how would I go about syncing the oscillators together?

[image: VCO]

Hard sync as defined by wikipedia: The leader oscillator's pitch is generated by user input (typically the synthesizer's keyboard), and is arbitrary. The follower oscillator's pitch may be tuned to (or detuned from) this frequency, or may remain constant. Every time the leader oscillator's cycle repeats, the follower is retriggered, regardless of its position. If the follower is tuned to a lower frequency than the leader it will be forced to repeat before it completes an entire cycle, and if it is tuned to a higher frequency it will be forced to repeat partway through a second or third cycle. This technique ensures that the oscillators are technically playing at the same frequency, but the irregular cycle of the follower oscillator often causes complex timbres and the impression of harmony. If the tuning of the follower oscillator is swept, one may discern a harmonic sequence.

This effect may be achieved by measuring the zero axis crossings of the leader oscillator and retriggering the follower oscillator after every other crossing.

Comment: If you sync the oscillators then you have, in effect, one oscillator so, there's no added benefit to the synth's sound when syncing them. So, my comment pretty much neutralizes your question but, if you have some cunning idea about what synchronization actually means to you (different to my opinion) then you should reveal that in order to keep the question from becoming closed down.

Comment: Does hard sync perhaps mean a fixed frequency difference, or frequency ratio between the two VCOs? As Andy says, if it mean identical frequency, then there will be no audible difference between them.

Comment: Added definition.

Comment: re hard sync, I would try, use a high value resistor (or series pot + resistor) connected from VCO#1 IC12/pin 6 to the same point in VCO#2; or, try going to VCO#2 IC12/pin 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the circuit shown, the base of Q7 is a summing junction for all the various control voltages in the unshaded portion of your diagram, including the circled pitch control.  Q7 itself produces a current at its collector that charges the timing capacitor C22; that current has an exponential relationship with the sum of the control voltages, so as to get a pitch that rises by an octave for some fixed increase in control voltage, typically 1V/octave after scaling.

For you to get two oscillators with any independence of pitch, you will need to sum the control voltages independently for each of them. This suggests introducing an op-amp or two to buffer those voltages that are fed to both oscillators: perhaps an op-amp to sum the voltages from the unshaded portion of the picture, with its output fed via two resistors to the bases of Q7 and Q7', together with a separate Tune potentiometer for each.  Or (to copy the Minimoog) a separate summing op-amp for each oscillator.

The function of FET transistor Q8 is to discharge C22 rapidly when its voltage reaches a threshold measured by the comparator IC12.  For oscillator sync, the aim is to reset oscillator 2 whenever oscillator 1 resets.  For this purpose, some synth designs include a second FET across C22 in oscillator 2 that is controlled by the comparator in oscillator 1 (with a switch to connect or disconnect the signal); others link the comparators in the two oscillators in other ways.

I have found that studying the schematics for the Minimoog and other synths is very helpful, though my own adventure in analog synth building has only just got off the ground.  The Minimoog does devote some resources to summing and routing control voltages to the oscillators.  Many other synth schematics are easily found online, including the Moog Rogue and Prodigy, both of which are pared-down designs like the one you are looking at, but (IIRC) have oscillator sync of one kind or another.

Comment: Thank you! Would that second FET be wired in parallel to the first? Also, the Transcendent has a nonstandard octave voltage (18 mV/IV5), how would I go about designing an op amp circuit for that?

Comment: When I have a moment, I will summarize what I know. Actually, I learned something new by reading the Transcendent article, so thanks for that!